# how to make animated view go away?

Tags: android, animation

I am using [NineOldAndroid](http://nineoldandroids.com/)'s AnimatorSet on a View

and when i want to get rid of the animation, and make the view gone - nothing happens

how do i make the view go away?

```
    public void showAnimation(boolean show) {
    if (show) {
        if (mTarget.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            // play sound

            mTarget.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            pauseAnimation = false;
            // start animation
            initTargetAnimation();
        }
    } else {

        pauseAnimation = true;    //All of this block gets executed in the debugger, but none of it actually take effect
        if (mTarget.getAnimation() != null) {
            mTarget.getAnimation().cancel();
            mTarget.clearAnimation();
        }
        mTarget.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



}

    private void initTargetAnimation() {

    final AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();

    // init animation properties
    set.playTogether(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTarget, "scaleX", RELEVANT_ANIMATION_SEQUENCE), ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mTarget, "scaleY", RELEVANT_ANIMATION_SEQUENCE));

    // add animation listener
    set.setDuration(1500).addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            // RESTART ANIMATION
            if (!pauseAnimation) {
                initTargetAnimation(); // TODO fix
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });

    // start animation
    set.start();

}
```

Comment: @Kerry if you are going to edit my post - perhaps you can answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

After you set the visibility on your View mTarget try calling invalidate() on it. This assumes you call it from the main thread otherwise it's postinvalidate().

Comment: i so wished it helped, but it still doesnt go away :(

Comment: the code i posted, is my full code short of 
mTarget = (View) fragment.findViewById(R.id.target)